# Opera - Trying to get rid of it, using Ububtu 22.04.2. Opera seems to be acting like a virus - removed it from Snaps and Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: apt, package-management, opera

Tried everything to rid my self of Opera. Removed from snaps list with some effort, removed completely from Synaptic Package Manager. My Software Updater still not working. Opera does not show-up on other software list any more. It shows up nowhere. I still get this ( see snap shot picture) I have seven other snap shots that I sent to Opera bug report they were not much help. Opera always worked good in the past but it seems more virus like now can't purge it like other stuff i tried searching and trying different things. I could not figure how to make a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu 22.04. I just had a old 18.04 CD from Free Geek Vancouver it worked but took a very long time to get to 22.04.2. This  Computer was a donation from ReBoot Vancouver with the Evil windows 11 that want a person to register and sign up for everything. I am no a computer geek but started using Ubuntu many decades ago. I just plug along with it and Ubuntu Mate when it first came out.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Remove it from your sources list: you added a PPA at some point and have not removed that. A PPA is not part of the installation and when you add it it needs to also be removed manually.

See `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` There will be an "opera" there. You can remove it using `rm` and then do `sudo apt update` or you can also do it from the desktop at the option "software & sources"

---

Like this:

```
$ more /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and check for opera and then do

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ 
alex-p-ubuntu-smplayer-lunar.list       
alex-p-ubuntu-smplayer-lunar.list.save  
google-chrome.list                      opera-stable.list
google-chrome.list.save                 opera-stable.list.save
```

also to check for opera. I mysqlf have chrome, smplayer, and opera. You can remove the 2 with "opera".

The error in the image clearly states you have a source that points to opera. Remove that.

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  did not show anything

Comment: /home/x/Downloads/Reply to answer 1 Screenshot from 2023-06-25 17-43-04.png

Comment: To the kindly person that answered. I did with the code cut and paste you suggested there was nothing listed. I then did a updated as my Software Updater is disabled by Opera. It was even this way when Opera was loaded and working for browsing. It only did this with Opera, when Opera updated. Every thing was good in the beginning with Opera and this computer then Opera caused Software Updater to crap out. I kept all the Screen shots from the beginning and sent to Operas bug report if there is a way posting to you, If too busy its OK

Comment: x@x-ThinkPad-E560:~$ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/: Is a directory
x@x-ThinkPad-E560:~$

Comment: /home/x/Downloads/Answer 1b Screenshot from 2023-06-25 18-23-31.png

Comment: +1 This is clearly the right answer.

Comment: @Raffa added that too :)